# How can you multiply a value from an Object.entry for another key value inside a loop?

Tags: javascript, function, loops, vue.js, vue-composition-api

I would like to add different worker values of each sector but multiply that value by another key:value property . This is a Vue.js composition API webapp.

```
export default {
  setup( props, {emit}) { 
  let data = reactive({

  let chosenCompanies:  [
        { id: 'Big',  workers: 250, clones: 9 },
        { id: 'Medium', workers: 75, clones: 2 },
        { id: 'Small', workers: 10, clones: 6 },
        { id: 'Individual', workers: 1, clones: 7}
      ]
});
const employedWorkers = () => {
  let employedworkersPrivate = 0;
  data.chosenCompanies.forEach(function(sector){
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(sector)) {
        if (key === 'workers') {
          employedworkersPrivate += parseInt(value)
       
  //  I need to multiply the number of workers per clones here, instead of just adding more workers 
  // can I get to the key 'clones' value here?

          }
    }
  })
  return employedworkersPrivate
}
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I did, just forgot to paste it when I cleaned up my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to iterate over the entries - instead access only the exact two keys you need, the `.workers` and `.clones`.

```js
let chosenCompanies =  [
        { id: 'Big',  workers: 250, clones: 9 },
        { id: 'Medium', workers: 75, clones: 2 },
        { id: 'Small', workers: 10, clones: 6 },
        { id: 'Individual', workers: 1, clones: 7}
      ]

const employedWorkers = () => {
  let employedworkersPrivate = 0;
  chosenCompanies.forEach(function(sector) {
    employedworkersPrivate += sector.workers * sector.clones;
  });
  return employedworkersPrivate;
};

console.log(employedWorkers());
```

Comment: unfortunately I think I do because I'm using Vue.js and chosenCompanies is a Proxy... I thought that would make no difference so I didn't mention that.

Comment: The new edited code's syntax `let data = reactive({ let chosenCompanies =  [` is invalid, can you paste in your actual code? But still, if you're iterating over the `chosenCompanies` inside a callback, it doesn't look like `chosenCompanies` would be a Proxy, it's an array

Answer (score 1):

You only need to iterate over `chosenCompanies` and access these values from each `sector`:

```js
const chosenCompanies =  [
  { id: 'Big',  workers: 250, clones: 9 },
  { id: 'Medium', workers: 75, clones: 2 },
  { id: 'Small', workers: 10, clones: 6 },
  { id: 'Individual', workers: 1, clones: 7}
];
let employedworkersPrivate = 0;

chosenCompanies.forEach(function(sector){
  employedworkersPrivate += sector.workers * sector.clones;
});

console.log(employedworkersPrivate);
```